# Spring Batch + Spring Boot - Single Job with each Step scheduled separately with a particular sequence

Tags: spring-batch, spring-scheduled

I have just started working with Spring Batch. I am using **Spring Batch(4.2.2) + Spring Boot(2.3.0)** and researching on how to design my problem in which I have multiple source files to be loaded into multiple DB tables, with each data load having different frequency.

Some data load is to be done thrice daily, some on daily basis, some quarterly etc. Also, there's dependency between them and a particular sequence is to be followed when they run.

Below is a scenario depicting the real problem(Source -> DB Table - Frequency of load):

> 1. Status.csv -> STATUS_CODES table - Annually (1st Jan every year at 1 AM).
> 2. Products.csv -> PRODUCTS table - Quarterly (1st Jan, 1st Apr, 1st Jul etc. at 1 AM)
> 3. Employee.csv -> EMP table - Daily (1 AM).
> 4. Franchises.csv -> FRANCHISE table - Weekly (Every Friday, 1 AM)
> 5. Used_Products_Sold.csv -> SALES table - Daily (1 AM).
> 6. Products_Sold.csv -> SALES table - Daily (1 AM).
> 7. Offers_Activated.csv -> SERV_ACTV table - Thrice daily (1 AM, 9 AM, 5 PM).
> 8. SERV_ACTV table -> SALES table - Thrice daily (1 AM, 9 AM, 5 PM).

Right now, I have encapsulated each of above flow into separate steps like loadStatusDataStep(#1), loadProductsDataStep(#2), loadEmployeeDataStep(#3) etc. I am trying to find out if each of these steps can be scheduled?

So, let's say, when Job runs on 1st Jan 2021(Friday) at 1 AM, below should be the Step sequence:

> Steps 1, 2 in parallel > Steps 3, 4 in parallel > Steps 5, 6 in parallel > Step 7 > Step 8

Job run On 1st Jan 2021(Friday) at 9 AM, Only steps 7 & 8 should run(because, others have already run on that day) and the Step sequence would be:

> Step 7 > Step 8

Job run On 2nd Jan 2021(Saturday) at 1 AM, Steps 1, 2 & 4 should not run and the Step sequence would be:

> Step 3 > Steps 5, 6 in parallel > Step 7 > Step 8

*Can this be achieved by Single Job with multiple steps? If yes, how can we define frequency for each step?*

Or, this has to be done by defining Separate Job for each(1 to 8), in which case, how to define sequence between those Jobs?

Would appreciate any help on how to approach/design it.

Comment: I would create a separate job for each file type (make each job do one thing and do it well). With that, your problem becomes a scheduling problem rather than a job design problem: how to schedule dependent tasks at different frequencies.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for your answer. This gives me a direction, and I'll create 8 Jobs, one for each flow and will schedule them accordingly. Now, how would Job2 know that Job1 has been completed successfully, and so, Job2 can start? Or that the Job1 failed and therefore, Job2 shouldn't start? Similar for other jobs in pipeline.

Comment: `how would Job2 know that Job1 has been completed successfully, and so, Job2 can start?`: the scheduler can use the exit code of job1 to drive the flow execution. This is explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#exitCodes. As mentioned, that's a job scheduling issue (out of scope of Spring Batch), and a common technique to implement flows of jobs is to use the exit code of the java process that runs the job.